# What are the benefits of using Cypress.io from inside an Angular application vs from outside?

Tags: angular, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

To make it more clear, here is what I exactly mean:

I sat up an angular project, a simple login/register angular app. Then I installed Cypress inside it, here is how the strucure looks like:

[image]

I run `npx cypress run` and all the tests run as expected.

Now, for experimenting purposes I installed a cypress on a stand-alone folder, and ran the same tests from there:

[image]

I run `npx cypress run` from the **stand-alone new Cypress folder** and the tests also behave as expected.

My question is, what is the different between the two setups?
Are there any benefits from using Cypress from inside an Angular project vs from a stand-alone folder?

Comment: To close the loop, afaik it's more of a convenience factor of where you install cypress, not that it will have special powers if placed inside your project. The main goal is to not test an external site because you don't control what happens to it https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites

Comment: Thanks! that explains it.